# Can the ablative of agent and a relative pronoun be used at the same time?

Tags: ablative, relative-pronouns

Here is an example of an ablative of agent for living things:

> "Puella a puero amata" = the girl loved by the boy

But is it correct if I add a relative pronoun to form:

> "Puella quae a puero amata" = the girl who loved by the boy (?)

Should I use *quam*? Or it is not grammatically correct?

Comment: Incidentally, while I see the term “ablative of agent” is well established, I find it misleading. The preposition *a/ab* requires the ablative, no matter if it has anything to do with agency, and that's that. Is there also an ablative of danger? (*a periculis tueri*) I don't think so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the ablative of agent in your example sentence is a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring), and you can state your question in more general terms. In fact, I think the simplest case to look at is a **noun + adjective**, since the *amata* in your case is functioning as an adjective.

The most important thing to know about a relative pronoun is that it begins a **relative clause**. A relative clause needs to be a full sentence with a verb, just as in English.

So, let's say we want to talk about a "strong girl." There are a few things we could do:

1. Attributive adjective

> Puella fortis...

Here, we simply have an attributive adjective modifying *puella*. In the nominative, it indicates that a "strong girl" is the subject, but it needs a verb or something else to be a complete sentence, e.g. *Puella fortis pugnat* = "The strong girl fights."

2. Predicative adjective

> Puella fortis est.

Here, you are expressing a complete thought: "The girl is strong."

3. Relative pronoun

> Puella quae fortis est...

Here, you are starting a relative clause after *puella*. You cannot say *puella quae fortis*, because *quae fortis* is not a complete thought. In this case, the English equivalent captures the disfluency pretty well: we don't say, "The girl who strong." Rather, we have to say, "The girl who **is** strong..." Note that this sentence still isn't complete: it's like the first example, *puella fortis*, and the main clause still needs to be completed, e.g. *Puella quae fortis est pugnat.* = "The girl who is strong fights."

To return to your example case, you would need to do two things:

1. Complete the relative clause
2. Complete the main clause

For example, you could write:

> *Puella quae a puero amata est...* = "The girl who **was loved** by the boy..."

(Note that *amata est* is the perfect passive: the present passive would be expressed by *amatur*.)

You would only write *quam* if the girl was the *direct object* of the sentence in the relative clause. For instance, you could write:

> *Puella quam puer amat...* = "The girl whom the boy loves..."

In short: treat the relative clause like an independent sentence. Just as "puella amata" is not a complete sentence, so "quae amata" is also incomplete: it needs a verb.

Latin *does* sometimes [omit the verb](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=AG+2.5.3.319&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0001), particularly copulae like *est*, but this would be confusing in a relative clause. There's at least one example to be found in the *Aeneid* (quoted in the linked A&G grammar section):

> accipe quae peragenda prius. (Aen. 6.136)

My intuition here is that the *gerundive* makes this construction more permissible. I could also see instances in a Ciceronian speech where a verb would be omitted, e.g. "quae facta, quae omissa bene scis..." but for your purposes I would recommend avoiding that kind of construction.

Comment: Maybe OT, but I wonder, if the relative clause was in the subjunctive: *Puella quam puer **amet***, what difference will it make? will it give it a general flavor like: "**a** girl  whom a boy loves?

Comment: @d_e Here's some helpful reading on that: http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/clauses-characteristic

Comment: thanks! I'll take a look.

Comment: @brianpck: The quote "accipe quae peragenda prius" was translated (Harvard) as "accept my counsel". It's like a cryptic clue; correct, but baffling to behold. For me it's: "accept what ought to be completed sooner/ better".